# Graph Api share_count rate limit

Tags: facebook-graph-api, count, share, limit, rate

We have a set of 40,000 Urls for which we are to build a console app which will call each of the urls using graph api 40,000 times :

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=URLHERE

According to FB documentation there is a rate limit on the graph API call per user. In our instance what would be the user equivalent to ?

How does FB determine the rate limit for our console app and what are our options if there is a limit? Does multi threading mean the limit will not be reached since each thread would mean a new user?

Comment: why would you even do that? hopefully it´s just a one time thing? not sure what you mean with multithreading, but you will definitely hit a limit if you want to do 40000 calls in a short time period.

Comment: Why : We need numbers for each of our URL shares to make some decisions in our internal tools